# Getting user name, lastname and ID in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I created a login/register using firebase, and it's working fine. 
But I need to get name and lastname from the user. How can I do this? And I'd like to know if it's possible to get an ID from the user, because I want to create a Rank Page in my app, so only an ID would be unique to do this.

Comment: Which auth method are you using for login?

Comment: I don't know if is this what are your asking, I'm using google and Email/Password.

Comment: To the google account I think it is easy to get the username and lastname,  but to the Email/Password firebase auth I have no idea on how it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get a Unique ID, you can use:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
String uid = user.getUid();
```

To get his name (I never tried this in Email/password auth, but it works fine on 3rd party providers auth):

```
String name = user.getDisplayName();
```

Answer (score 1):

For google sign-in you can use:

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personGivenName = acct.getGivenName();
  String personFamilyName = acct.getFamilyName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  String personId = acct.getId();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl();
}
```

[link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people)