# How can I get the user profile and name from Firebase?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase

My code shows only `undefined`. I want it to show user name, profile image, and user email. Thanks for help in advance.

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  //My Configuration
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var mainUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userNameId, userEmailId, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

if (mainUser != null) {
  userNameId = user.displayName;
  userEmailId = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
  uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
  // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
  // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
document.write(userNameId);
document.write(userEmailId);
document.write(photoUrl);
document.write(emailVerified);
document.write(uid);
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. In order to increase your chances of receiving a positive response to your query please read and consider the points raised in the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of this site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting user name, lastname and ID in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056333/getting-user-name-lastname-and-id-in-firebase)

Comment: No bro it's for application I am working for a website

Comment: Forgive me if I am overlooking something but what do you expect this `userNameId = user.displayName;` to do when `user` is undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user variable is not defined. Change the mainUser to user instead:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCfX0ye2p4W8Jq2Za3H0_nRpgtFAlGxFxA",
  authDomain: "trendy-cart-79671.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://trendy-cart-79671.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "trendy-cart-79671",
  storageBucket: "trendy-cart-79671.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "563099031291",
  appId: "1:563099031291:web:1fe8d3c43e2dfd8429425e"
};
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var userNameId, userEmailId, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified;

if (user != null) {
  userNameId = user.displayName;
  userEmailId = user.email;
  photoUrl = user.photoURL;
  emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
  uid = user.uid; // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use
  // this value to authenticate with your backend server, if
  // you have one. Use User.getToken() instead.
}
document.write(userNameId);
document.write(userEmailId);
document.write(photoUrl);
document.write(emailVerified);
document.write(uid);
```

Comment: It Also Didn't Worked Bro

Comment: Have you signed in with an auth provider, before executing this code? -
        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider())

Comment: Yes, i have signed in with an auth provider

Comment: In that case, if you execute this in your browser console what does it say:
console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser);